# TFS Work Item - custom field with type GUID

Tags: tfs

I am trying to create a custom Work Item Type in my TFS 2013 environment. 
I am adding a new field and setting the type="GUID". The WIT imports into the project ok, but when I try to open the designer through Process Editor it fails saying 'GUID' not found. I changed the type="String" and it worked. According to this document, it says a valid type is GUID. Any ideas?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337627(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: While I agree that it is on the list it is not something that I ever heard of or saw before. It looks like it was introduced in 2010.

Comment: Have you tried to add the field but nit add it to the UI?

Comment: Yes, I just added to my XML file and I imported that XML file and it worked. However, I get the same error when trying to open the imported WIT in the UI.

Comment: Have you tried setting a default value of guid? Ot may be complaining because it is empty